# django, travsersing multiple tables (models) in a filter

Tags: django

I have a functioning search function shown below, it works without issue. We are redesigning the system, the area_easting value now sits in its own table (model). To get to the area_easting he route is as follows: Trench.trench_id --> Context.context_id --> Sample.sample_id (I know this is non-standard notation).

So how would I traverse these joins? Something like:

```
qs = qs.filter(sample_id__context_id__trench_id__area_easting__icontains=easting_query)
```

Which returns `Unsupported lookup 'context_id' for AutoField or join on the field not permitted.`

```
from excavation.models import Trench, Context, Sample
from ceramic.models import Ceramic
...

def CeramicFliterView(request):
    qs = Sample.objects.all()
    easting_query = request.GET.get('area_easting')

    if easting_query != '' and easting_query is not None:
        qs = qs.filter(area_easting__icontains=easting_query)
    ...
```

Models.py

```
class Trench(models.Model):
    trench_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    area_easting = models.IntegerField()
    area_northing = models.IntegerField()
...

class Context(models.Model):
    context_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    trench_id = models.ForeignKey(Trench, db_column='trench_id', on_delete = models.PROTECT)
...

class Sample(models.Model):
    sample_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    context_id = models.ForeignKey(Context, db_column='context_id', on_delete = models.PROTECT)
...

class Ceramic(models.Model):
    ceramic_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    sample_id = models.ForeignKey(Sample, db_column='sample_id', on_delete = models.PROTECT)
```

Comment: sample_id and other id's fields you mentioned - they are foreign keys, right?

Comment: correct, I'll add a summary of the models.py to make it clearer

Comment: I think then you should remove `_id` suffix `qs = qs.filter(sample__context__trench__area_easting__icontains=easting_query)`

Comment: The suffix _id is part of the column name, I know this is not the Django way as I stated. Models added above.

Comment: hm, `qs` is already a `Sample` model so first try to change query to `qs.filter(context_id__trench_id__area_easting__icontains=easting_query)` Also this is kind of bad schema design when using with Django.

Comment: This solved it, in my application I needed to use iexact, I'm now trying to figure out how to get the area_easting in the template. I tried `{% for sherd in queryset %} {{ sherd.context_id.trench_id.area_easting }}` without luck. Also, regarding schema, the database conforms to database theory rather than Django's rather awkward way of dealing with relational databases. With Django you can use databases without understanding databases, not a good approach In my opinion - maybe I'm getting old.

Comment: if you write this up as an answer I'll accept it, thanks.